# почему не работает @input в ангуляр

Tags: angular

подскажите где ошибка. не хочет работать @input в ангуляре, вроде и импортирован и синтаксис правильный пишет  error TS2304: Cannot find name 'input'.

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-car',
  templateUrl: './car.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./car.component.css']
})
export class CarComponent {

    @input() carItem : {name: string, year: number};
}
```

Comment: Напишите @Input с большой буквы, скорее всего заработает.

Comment: =)))))))) спасибо. пол инета перелопатил=)) а тут все просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript регистрозависимый язык, поэтому писать нужно `@Input` с большой буквы, так как это название директивы прописано внутри Angular.